# Can map/flatMap sequence with several paths be translated a for-comprehension?

Tags: scala

I think it's not possible but maybe I'm missing something?

Here is an example

```
val sentences = "hello.what is your name?I am Loïc"     

sentences.split("\\.|\\?").flatMap { sentence =>
  if (sentence.startsWith("h")) sentence.split(" ").map(word => word.toUpperCase)
  else if (sentence.startsWith("w")) sentence.split(" ").flatMap(word => List(word.toUpperCase, "-").map(word => word.toUpperCase))
  else List(sentence)
}
```

Can this be translated to a for-comprehension expression?

I noticed that I have this kind of pattern quite often when I'm using map/flatMap on futures (for example on webservice calls), if I need to pattern-match on the service response. So I'm trying to improve the readability.

Thanks :)

Comment: what you mean by 'for comprehension expression'? you want to transform a flatMap to a foreach loop??

Comment: @eliasah I mean something like for {
  book <- books
  if book.author startsWith "bob" 
} yield book.title
which can be translated in 
books.filter(book => book.author startsWith "bob").map(book => book.title)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can translate the outer construct into a for/yield, and branches of the if/else into their own for/yields:

```
for {
  sentence ← sentences.split("\\.|\\?")
  out ← if (sentence.startsWith("h"))
      for {word ← sentence.split(" ")} yield word.toUpperCase
    else if (sentence.startsWith("w"))
      for {word ← sentence.split(" ")
           w ← List(word.toUpperCase, "-") } yield w.toUpperCase
    else List(sentence)
} yield out
```

If you can extract some commonality from the branches you might be able to combine them into a single higher-order function call rather than an if/else, e.g. by using scalaz's `traverse`, or using polymorphism by having `sentence` be an object with subclasses so that the branch just becomes a method call. But in general if there's nothing at all in common between the branches then you'll have to handle them separately (which makes sense, no?).